# Retrieve Credentials from Windows Credentials Store using C# in ASP.net website under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, credential-manager

Retrieve Credentials from Windows Credentials Store problem using C# in ASP.net website under IIS
I am using following code

```
var cm = new Credential();
cm.Target = "targetname";
cm.Type = CredentialType.Generic;
if (!cm.Exists())
{
    Console.WriteLine("cm is null");
}
cm.Load();
Console.WriteLine("Password: " + cm.Password);
Console.WriteLine("Username: " + cm.Username);'
```

Above code running on windows server 2012 R under IIS. But above code is not able to retrieve username and password.(cm is null always)
I used same code in my console application and works fine.
Please let me know any special instruction need to follow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you use IIS 7 you could try to enable "Load User Profile" parameter.
You can find it: Application Pools --> Right click button under your service name --> Advance Settings 
Set "Load User Profile" true.

Comment: The question is not about just gaining the credentials, but gaining the credentials programatically. Your answer does not provide a solution to that problem

Comment: I see , thanks. I will send programmatically example soon.